# Using Kivy to call pygame joystick data collection

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, kivy

Okay, so I have been trying to call a function that uses pygame.joystick to take input from 2 Logitech 3d extreme pro joysticks. When I use strictly pygame, the joysticks are recognized and are working. But when I try to call a similar function within the kv language, I get this error.

```
   File "MainUI__1-2.py", line 179, in <module>
     MainClass().run()
   File "/home/mlees/kivy_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 829, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "MainUI__1-2.py", line 175, in build
     return tabpanelkv()
   File "/home/mlees/kivy_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/uix/tabbedpanel.py", line 482, in __init__
     super(TabbedPanel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/home/mlees/kivy_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/uix/gridlayout.py", line 256, in __init__
     super(GridLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/home/mlees/kivy_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/uix/layout.py", line 76, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/home/mlees/kivy_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 361, in __init__
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/mlees/kivy_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 469, in apply_class_lang_rules
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/mlees/kivy_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 538, in apply
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/mlees/kivy_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 659, in _apply_rule
     child, crule, rootrule, rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/mlees/kivy_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 659, in _apply_rule
     child, crule, rootrule, rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/mlees/kivy_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 654, in _apply_rule
     child = cls(__no_builder=True)
   File "MainUI__1-2.py", line 129, in __init__
     self.Joy1B = pygame.joystick.Joystick(self.joy1A)
 TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)
```

However I am giving that line a integer. The code below is what I am currently trying to get working. The joysticks that I am using are at positions 0 and 1 (pygame's doing not the computers). Here is my code:

```
# Main Code for control code
# Kivy for front end UI
# pygame for backend Joystick code
# opencv for camera control

# 1. Import necessary libraries
# 1.1 Kivy libraries and imports
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty


# 1.2 other libraries needed that are not a part of kivy
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import serial
import time

# 2. Variables (declared after structural code is done)
pygame.init()
pygame.joystick.init()

Lateral_X_Y = 0
Vertical_Z = 0
S1_Data = 0
S2_Data = 0
S3_Data = 0
S4_Data = 0
Lights = 0

In_Min = float(-1)
In_Max = float(1)
Out_Min = float(1000)
Out_Max = float(2000)
Scaled_Out_Min = float(1250)
Scaled_Out_Max = float(1750)

startMarker = '<'
endMarker = '\n'
dividingmarker = ','

# arduino = serial.Serial(port="COM14", baudrate=115200, timeout=0.01)
time.sleep(.01)

Builder.load_string("""

<tabpanelkv>:
    size_hint: 1, 1
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Cameras'
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            cols: 2
            GridLayout:
                size_hint: 1.7, 1
                rows: 1
                cols: 1
                KivyCamera:
                    cam: 0
            GridLayout:
                rows: 2
                cols: 1
                KivyCamera:
                    cam: 2
                Button:
                    text: 'Cam3'

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Diagnostics'
        GridLayout:
            rows: 4
            cols: 1
            JoystickValue:
                joy1A: 0
                joy2A: 1

""")

class KivyCamera(Image):
    cam = ObjectProperty()
    fps = NumericProperty(30)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._capture = None
        if self.cam is not None:
            self._capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self.cam)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / self.fps)

    def on_cam(self, *args):
        if self._capture is not None:
            self._capture.release()
        self._capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self.cam)

    @property
    def capture(self):
        return self._capture

    def update(self, dt):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        if ret:
            buf1 = cv2.flip(frame, 0)
            buf = buf1.tostring()
            image_texture = Texture.create(
                size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt="bgr"
            )
            image_texture.blit_buffer(buf, colorfmt="bgr", bufferfmt="ubyte")
            self.texture = image_texture

class JoystickValue(GridLayout):
    joy1A = ObjectProperty()
    joy2A = ObjectProperty()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(JoystickValue, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.Joy1B = pygame.joystick.Joystick(self.joy1A)
        self.Joy2B = pygame.joystick.Joystick(self.joy2A)

        self.Joy1B.init()
        self.Joy2B.init()
        self.Xmovdata = ObjectProperty()
        self.Ymovdata = ObjectProperty()
        self.Zmovdata = ObjectProperty()
        self.Userdata = ObjectProperty()
        self.TserData = ObjectProperty()
        self.OserData = ObjectProperty()
        self.CTserData = ObjectProperty()
        self.StupidFuck = ObjectProperty()

    def JoyRead(self):
        self.Joy1X = self.Joy1B.get_axis(0)
        self.Joy1Y = self.Joy1B.get_axis(1)

        self.Joy2X = self.Joy2B.get_axis(0)
        self.Joy2Y = self.Joy2B.get_axis(1)

        # Buttons on Joy1: 2,3,6,7,8,9,10
        self.Joy1B2 = self.Joy1B.get_button(1)
        self.Joy1B3 = self.Joy1B.get_button(2)
        self.Joy1B6 = self.Joy1B.get_button(5)
        self.Joy1B7 = self.Joy1B.get_button(6)
        self.Joy1B8 = self.Joy1B.get_button(7)
        self.Joy1B9 = self.Joy1B.get_button(8)
        self.Joy1B10 = self.Joy1B.get_button(9)

        # Buttons for Joy2: 1, 6
        self.Joy2B1 = self.Joy2B.get_button(0)
        self.Joy2B6 = self.Joy2B.get_button(5)

        # Hat switch for Joy1
        self.Joy1HF = self.Joy1B.get_hat(0)

        print(str(self.Joy1X))

# 5. tabpanelkv class
class tabpanelkv(TabbedPanel):
    pass

# 6. Main Class
class MainClass(App, GridLayout):
    def build(self):
        return tabpanelkv()

# 7. Main Loop
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainClass().run()
```

I have gotten the cameras to work correctly, but now the joysticks are giving me issues. I going to be eventually outputting the data collected to the second tab (baby steps to get to that point. If you have any suggestions comment them) Any help is appreciated at this point. I have been trying to get this to work (trying different ideas) for the last few hours.
Ideas I have tried:

1. Changing the self.Joy1A and self.Joy2A within these lines  `self.Joy1B = pygame.joystick.Joystick(self.joy1A)` and  `self.Joy2B = pygame.joystick.Joystick(self.joy2A)` to straight 0 and 1. But then I can't call the JoyRead() function that follows. (At least i think i can't, I might be wrong)
2. Taking option 1 and then calling the function later on in the code (I honestly forgot where I called it from).
3. Consulting with friends to try find a solution.
4. Putting the pygame.joystick.Joystick lines within an if statement such as below:

```
        if self.joy1A is not None or self.joy2A is not None:
            self.Joy1B = pygame.joystick.Joystick(self.joy1A)
            self.Joy2B = pygame.joystick.Joystick(self.joy2A)
```

Any help is as always much appreciated.

Comment: code `print(self.joy1A)` gives me `None` - better use directly numbers `Joystick(0)` or define in Python `self.joy1A = 0` or `joy1A = ObjectProperty(defaultvalue=0)`. Code from `kv` can be executed after `__init__()`

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that `__init__` is executed before `Kivy` executes  `kv`.

You can set values directly in code

```
class JoystickValue(GridLayout):

    joy1A = ObjectProperty(0)
    joy2A = ObjectProperty(1)
```

Or you have to use `sheduler` to run this code little later and `Kivy` will have time to execute `kv`.

```
class JoystickValue(GridLayout):

    joy1A = ObjectProperty()
    joy2A = ObjectProperty()
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        #print('self.joy1A:', self.joy1A)
        
        Clock.schedule_once(self.set_joys, 0.1)

    def set_joys(self, arg):

        #print('self.joy1A:', self.joy1A)
        
        self.Joy1B = pygame.joystick.Joystick(self.joy1A)
        self.Joy2B = pygame.joystick.Joystick(self.joy2A)

        # ... rest ...
```